# How to add the third party library in Vapor using cocoapods?

Tags: swift, cocoapods, shared-libraries, vapor

I wanted to add a third party library but unfortunately Vapor doesn't support pod init. I was wondering what other way one can add the library to a Vapor app? (other than adding files manually)

Comment: Make a fork of the library and add `Package.swift` for it to make it available via Swift Package Manager and then add it to `Package.swift` of your Vapor application.

Comment: If any help with `Package.swift` is needed please ask in Vapor's Discord chat